# Midrash about 10 commandments

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, agada-stories-legends

Looking for a midrash that says that after the Chet HaEgel, Moshe told Gd “the 10 commandments are in singular form. Bnei Yisrael thought they were directed solely to me and not to them”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shemos Rabbah 43](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.43.5?lang=bi) (referenced by Rashi on 20:2):

> Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai:
> The Holy One blessed be He gave Moses at Sinai an opening for a
> response [by saying]: “I am the Lord your God” (Exodus 20:2). When
> Israel crafted the calf, Moses was placating God, but He did not
> listen to him. He said to him: ‘Is it possible that the attribute of
> justice will not be implemented against them for having violated the
> precept?’ Moses said: ‘Master of the universe, so you said at Sinai:
> “I am the Lord your God [Elohekha],” Eloheikhem  was not stated. Did
> You not say it to me? Did You say it to them? Did I violate the
> precept?’